# Nested virtualization on (OpenStack on ESXi on Windows)

Tags: virtualization, esxi, openstack

For the last few weeks I have been reading a lot about OpenStack, Cloud Computing, virtualization, VMware tools and I have decided to try it. I would like to install, configure it and try it to see how it works. For the last few days I have had troubles installing it.

I want to try it install on my laptop in an appropriate way as in a server room. Now I am a little bit confused, and I would like to get some help with the network configuration and get answers for my questions. Can one one explan mi how to do it.

My laptop specifications:

```
 CPU: Core i5, dual core 2.5Ghz with Intel virtualization technology
 RAM: 6GB
 SSD: 256GB
 One LAN adapter
 One WLAN adapter (I am not using this at all)
 OS: Windows Windows 7 64-bit
```

I am using VMware Workstation 9, ESXi 5.5 and vSphere, I don't use vCenter or vSphere web application.

Inside a VMware Workstation I have installed ESXi 5.5 with specification:

```
 RAM 2GB, 
 2 processors, 
 1 network adapter using NAT
 hostname: localhost
 IP Address: 192.168.186.140
 Network identit acquired from DHCP server 192.168.186.254
```

Inside ESXi I have the option "Test Management Network" where I can ping some IPs, It works.

```
 Ping Address #0: 192.168.186.2
 Ping Address #1: 192.168.186.2
 Ping Address #2: blank
 Resolve Hostname localhost.localdomain
```

I haven't made any configuration inside ESXi and for ESXi in workstation I am using NAT and enabled option "Synchronize guest time with host". With vSphere I connect to ESXi by using IP: 192.168.186.140, username and password.

Inside vSphere I have two virtual machines installing Ubuntu server 14.04, and my plan later is to install OpenStack on it.

Specifications of both virtual machines is the same (I will change it later if there will be any need):

```
 CPU 1
 RAM 512 MB
 One network adapter using VM Network
```

The first virtual machine is a CONTROLLER node and second virtual machine is COMPUTE. CONTROLLER I want to use as controller node for OpenStack, other as a compute node. I have started with installation of OpenStack components by following the instructions from the install guide. That means I will use two nodes installation. I have come to this step: http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/basics-networking-nova-verify.html and I have problem with pinging from CONTROLLER to COMPUTE and inversely. I can ping google.com.

I thought I will resolve this issue later and move on with the installation. In point four of this section: http://docs.openstack.org/icehouse/install-guide/install/apt/content/keystone-install.html when I type:

```
 su -s /bin/sh -c "keystone-manage db_sync" keystone
```

get this error:

```
 2014-07-18 19:30:30.682 6656 CRITICAL keystone [-] OperationError: (OperationalError)  (2005,
```

"Unknown MySQL server host 'controller' (0)") None None

I have been googled it and found out that there is something wrong with my network configuration, which means there is something wrong with localhost which takes us back to the network problem.

Netowork interfaces and host of bouth Ubuntu servers:

CONTROLLER NODE:

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
 address: 10.0.0.11 //AS IN INSTALLATION GUIDE
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 gateway 10.0.0.1
```

cat etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1 controller
 #controler 
 10.0.0.11 controller
 #compute
 10.0.0.31 compute
```

COMPUTE NODE:

cat /etc/network/interfaces

```
 auto lo
 iface lo inet loopback
 auto eth0
 iface eth0 inet dhcp
 address: 10.0.0.31 //AS IN INSTALLATION GUIDE
 netmask 255.255.255.0
 network 10.0.0.0
 gateway 10.0.0.1
 auto eth1
  iface eth1 inet manual
  up ip link set dev $IFACE up
  down ip link set dev $IFACE down
```

cat etc/hosts

```
 127.0.0.1 compute
 #compute 
 10.0.0.31 compute
 #controler 
 10.0.0.31 controler
```

Before I begin work with installing OpenStack components and before that, solving this issue I have some questions:

Is it possible on laptop to install in this way OpenStack? I know it is much easier using devstack one node installation (I have already tried it) but I would like to now how OpenStack works, what exactly is virtualization, how to launch virtual machine inside OpenStack. Don't get confused with virtual machines inside VMware and vSphere.

Is it possible to have nested virtualization, so that the first virtualization is on workstation and ESXi for Ubuntu server virtual machine, and the second virtualization is inside OpenStack for providing instances with flavor settings?

Can anyone help me with configuring these network problems, obviously I cannot continue with OpenStack installation. Should I use virtual switches and routing? I would like to have management network and public network so I can't inside Windows browser get horizon and launch some instances. I install LAMP on it. Because I just want to get proof of this concept.

Should I configure network on both Ubuntu servers and also inside vSphere? I think I should.

I do not understand IPs on ESXi "Test Management Network" used for ping tests. Because IP of ESXi is 192.168.186.140.

Comment: I want to achieve something like this guy did: youtube.com/watch?v=I2gBypQaxqk. Below is a picture of my network in vSphere: http://postimg.org/image/3kua5hx2l/

I would like to do on VMware tools as this guy do it VirtualBox. http://uksysadmin.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/running-openstack-under-virtualbox-a-complete-guide/ http://uksysadmin.wordpress.com/2011/02/24/running-openstack-under-virtualbox-a-complete-guide-part-2/

Comment: You mentioned the venerable devstack project - it's probably still the best utility/tool for learning about the ins and outs of openstack - and you should be able to manipulate the configuration to be able to install to multiple nodes (for different parts/services of the stack)